# Keys have been shuffled, boards turned

Tags: cipher

Some person decided to mix up my keys, and I forgot where my letters are.

> This is a keyboard cipher

```
Fqji.br.hqrcu;wa-.'ubquvq.'zw;cjqa.ye
```

> US Keyboard

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually not very good with ciphers but I think I got this one:

> Shift each key twice to the right on a qwerty US keyboard.

So it is:

> Help my keyboard someone scrambled it.

Also

> For semicolon and apostrophe, you go back to the beginning of the row of keys, so the semicolon is "a" and apostrophe is "s".

Comment: Yes, the answer is correct, but I don't know what you mean by the 3rd note

Comment: For the semicolon and apostrophe, you go back to the beginning of the home row.

Comment: Oh. Yes you do, the entire keyboard is a loop (because 1. it ends eventually and 2. i can't like caps lock key or windows key)